# How to remove database from emulator?

Tags: android, sqlite

I have the database times in my application running on the emulator and want to remove it. Is there any sqlite query I can run via shell or another method?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Go to DDMS then go to file explorer then open data-->--->data--> then your package ---> then database and here you have your database and you can delete it by clicking minus "-" sign from top right.

Comment: Its required to have emulator running while checking files through Fire Explorer in DDMS.

Answer (score 0):

yes the database can be accessed via the device bridge from the shell...

here is a link to the explination on android.com

http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/adb.html#sqlite

Answer (score 0):

Use command adb shell,
Then navigate to your app , typically in /data/data/your_appname/
there you will find a directory called databases , typically here all the apps database is    stored. you can see the database created .
Either you can delete this file or enter sqlite shell and delete database sqlite way.

Answer (score 0):

You can also have a totally fresh start if you erase all apps and content from the emulator like this

```
>>./emulator -avd <AVDNAME> -wipe-clean
```

Where `emulator` is in the `android-sdk-YOUROS\tools` directory.

You can find out what your avd name is by doing

```
>>./android list avds
```

Where `android` is also in the `android-sdk-YOUROS\tools` directory.

This will restore the emulator to the "factory default" settings, so it will look like it's a brand new phone.